# Timeout after restart iis application .net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

After restarting website and/or application pool in IIS the first requests to an SQL server database times out.

I get one of the following two errors

> The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login
> handshake acknowledgement

> The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the
> pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in
> use and max pool size was reached

on the first request with fetch from the client side, the next call after 1 minute works just fine. So for some reason, there is some sort of cold start or something when starting the application.

I have tested using both Entity Framework and standard SqlConnection in .NET Core with same result.

Any idea where to start?

Comment: After release the application not start immediatly but after the first call.... Try to do a smockTest after you CI/CD process

Comment: Sounds like you're not disposing your connections properly.

Comment: According your description, you have test ` both Entity Framework and standard SqlConnection`. So I think the connectionstrings should be same in your test project. [So could you kindly check this thread, connect your DB and get connection string in VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728299/7687666).

Comment: This step could help us to verify it's connection error or not.

Comment: It has nothing to do with disposing objects. This is first call, there are no open connections and the pool should, as far as I know, be empty.

I have tested connectionstrings with hostname\\namedinstance and IP, port with same result.

Other projects are connecting fine, and running Mangement studio is working 100% fine as well

Comment: Hi @Pochen, could you kindly follow my suggestion to generate the correct connectionstring, I know the corrent connectionstring can work except the first time when the application restart. I mean maybe there are some settings in the connectionstring may casue this issue.

Comment: And pls also check the application logs in EventViewer, maybe we can find some usefully things.